# New Nexus 4 download issue

Tags: google-apps

I try to save a .mp3 attachment from an email in hotmail.com. it loops and drained my battery. It continues to loop even phone restarts. I forced it to stop via download manager. is it only my phone or is it some unfixed bugs in download manager?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the download manager won't clear its cache, goto settings/apps/download manager and clear data (cache will be cleared as well). It won't erase any already downloaded items, but the items trying to download. If you can, run a logcat, to get an idea of what is going wrong. Good luck!!